# How to lie about the error codes without specifying servlet locations?

Tags: java, tomcat, http-status-codes

In Tomcat we can specify fragment like the following  in `web.xml` of the web app to define a custom error handler:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/SomeServlet</location>
</error-page>
```

and it's also possible to override built-in page for all error code with one handler:

```
<error-page>
    <location>/SomeServlet</location>
</error-page>
```

As we can see, when we are doing this there is always a custom handler; in the fragments above it's `/SomeServlet`.

But I'm thinking that what if I'm just wanting to lie about the specific error code with another existing built-in handler, for example, lying that an `HTTP 404` was an `HTTP 401`, and respond with `HTTP 401`'s built-in handler.

How could I do this or is it even possible? If not, what would be the best practice to lie about the error code by using Tomcat's built-in libraries?

Comment: What's the problem that you intend to solve? Security by obscurity?

Comment: @OlafKock: Security by obscurity .. yep; I'm trying to find a zero code solution though.

Comment: That sounds like IPSEC.  (Surely there's no security hazard if error responses are shown to authorized users ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to change the response code without writing any code?

Try using [url-rewrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).

First, map the url-rewrite Filter to an arbitrary URL (like `/fake-responses/404`). Then, create a rewrite rule that matches `/fake-responses/404` and sets the response status code to 401 (or whatever). It might make more sense to call the target URL `/fake-responses/401` since that will be what is returned to the client.

Comment: Aw, no bounty for my accepted response. :( Oh, well.

Comment: Sorry for 4 years later .. I guess I missed the grace period at that time

Answer (score 1):

Implement your own [HttpServletResponse](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) and use it. In this way you could set `<error-code>` for one code and return response for another code in HTTP response.

Another aproach would be to implement your own [Servlet Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html) but this has significant performance impact.

Use google for examples how to implement it.

Comment: I in fact did both. But I'm not aware of a way of implementing only HttpServletResponse without implementing a filter also to control the error response globally.

Comment: @KenKin [this link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/527683/Servlets/java/manipulate-HttpServletResponse-content-ServletFilter) has some examples

Comment: What I meant is I know how to implement both the response wrapper and the filter, but if I choose this technique I must do them all. Your answer sounds like there are two approaches.

Comment: @KenKin in coment I have posted above is link to article containing some links to another articles. read and try them. at first, read [basics](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) and [example](http://punekaramit.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/intercepting-http-response-using-servlet-filter/). it's up to you if you will implement only your own httpservletresponse (you just need response with 401 code when there is 404 error) or you need some extended processing and checks with filter.

Answer (score 1):

This one looked like fun, so I took a crack.

Sadly, I couldn't find a good way to do this with configuration only.  I did, however, come up with a way to allow you to set a single filter in your web.xml and "re-designate" all of your HTTP status codes through the init params of that filter.

Something to note that makes this answer differ from the other answers is that I did indeed implement **both** a Filter and a HttpServletResponseWrapper because I wanted to trap all corner cases, including where the response is [committed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#isCommitted%28%29) prior to the filter receiving the response.  This commit can happen in various places such as client code calling [HttpServletResponse#sendError](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int%29), frameworks, etc.

Anyway...with your web.xml fragment would look something like:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>HttpStatusCodeFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.stackoverflow.HttpStatusCodeConverter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>502</param-name>
        <param-value>403</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>405</param-name>
        <param-value>403</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HttpStatusCodeFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and your Servlet Filter (and inner HttpServletResponseWrapper class) like this:

```
public class HttpStatusCodeConverter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger
            = Logger.getLogger(HttpStatusCodeConverter.class.getName());
    private Map<Integer, Integer> errorMap;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            AntiCommitResponseWrapper hr = new AntiCommitResponseWrapper(
                    (HttpServletResponse) response);

            //pre-filter check for error codes, if code exists, no need to continue
            if (!hasFilterCode(hr)) {
                //no error yet, progress through filters
                try {
                    chain.doFilter(request, hr);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    if (!hasFilterCode(hr)) {
                        //exception from a filter but no code was set, set it now
                        hr.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                    }
                }
            }

            //do post-filter check for error codes
            if (hasFilterCode(hr)) {
                hr.sendError(errorMap.get(hr.getStatus()));
            }

            hr.complete();
        }

    }

    private boolean hasFilterCode(HttpServletResponse hr) {
        return errorMap != null && errorMap.containsKey(hr.getStatus());
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        errorMap = new HashMap<>();
        Enumeration<String> paramNames = filterConfig.getInitParameterNames();
        while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = paramNames.nextElement();
            try {
                errorMap.put(Integer.valueOf(name),
                        Integer.valueOf(filterConfig.getInitParameter(name)));
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Invalid HTTP status code mapping "
                        + "''{0}''->''{1}''.", 
                        new Object[]{name, filterConfig.getInitParameter(name)});
            }
        }
    }

    private class AntiCommitResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

        private int status = SC_OK;
        private String statusMsg;
        private String redirectLocation;
        private final ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        public AntiCommitResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
            super(response);
        }

        @Override
        public int getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        @Override
        public void setStatus(int sc) {
            this.status = sc;
        }

        @Override
        public void sendRedirect(String location) throws IOException {
            this.status = SC_FOUND;
            this.redirectLocation = location;
        }

        @Override
        public void sendError(int sc) throws IOException {
            this.status = sc;
        }

        @Override
        public void sendError(int sc, String msg) throws IOException {
            this.status = sc;
            this.statusMsg = msg;
        }

        @Override
        public void resetBuffer() {
            buffer.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() {
            buffer.reset();
            status = SC_OK;
            statusMsg = null;
            super.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        }

        @Override
        public void setBufferSize(int size) {
        }

        @Override
        public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ServletOutputStream() {

                @Override
                public boolean isReady() {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void setWriteListener(WriteListener writeListener) {
                    try {
                        writeListener.onWritePossible();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void write(int i) throws IOException {
                    buffer.write(i);
                }
            };
        }

        /**
         * Send everything to the client.
         */
        private void complete() throws IOException {
            if (status != SC_OK) {
                super.sendError(status, statusMsg);
            } else if (status == SC_FOUND) {
                super.sendRedirect(redirectLocation);
            } else {
                super.setStatus(status);
                try (OutputStream out = super.getOutputStream()) {
                    out.write(buffer.toByteArray());
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In the end, for testing, I ended up creating the HttpStatusCodeConverter as a [web-fragment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/javaee6overview-part2-136353.html#webfrags) for Servlet 3.0 and made it available on [github](https://github.com/smsiebe/httpStatusRecodeFragment), if you're interested.  You can either fork the project, add your own filter params, and throw it onto your classpath...or, add it to your CP, and override the web-fragment filter params by adding your own  configuration within your web.xml.

Comment: I'm wondering how do you deal with a response which is already wrapped with `org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade`.

Comment: I don't think that will be an issue at all.  I assume that the ResponseFacade is actually the object I'm wrapping...but even if it's not, and the HttpStatusCodeConverter is instead wrapped by ResponseFacade, there shouldn't be a problem because the javadoc for ResponseFacade states "All methods are delegated to the wrapped response.", so it would just let the code converter filter do it's job.  I'll try it out later (probably won't be for a couple hours) and report back.

Comment: Worked without a problem on Tomcat 7.0.56. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring, the answer surely lies there, not in Tomcat. That's a big if though. I can't see Tomcat being able to do stuff like that. However this isn't exactly zero code.

> Normally any unhandled exception thrown when processing a web-request causes the server to return an HTTP 500 response. However, any exception that you write yourself can be annotated with the @ResponseStatus annotation (which supports all the HTTP status codes defined by the HTTP specification). When an annotated exception is thrown from a controller method, and not handled elsewhere, it will automatically cause the appropriate HTTP response to be returned with the specified status-code.

Answer (score -1):

Forwarding directly to error pages not to error handler. Maybe this can be accessible for you:

```
<error-code>500</error-code>
<location>/resources/errorPage404.jsp</location>
```

Comment: Er .. well, let's think servlets and server pages the same thing here.